# Monitor internal queues within application

Tags: performance, monitor

I have a few queues(not MSMQ) within a messaging system, and they basically receive and dispatch messages based on priority. Our client requests to monitor these queues on queue length by given timeframe.

I have looked into performance monitor, but it only offer insights at application level, not individual queue level.

Is there any solution which doesn't put any pressure on messaging system while providing perf info. of these queues?

Answer (score 0):

Being as there isn't really a standard around queues, (not to my knowledge,) it depends on the individual queueing system. Some of them will provide monitoring. Some you're going to have to write your own scripts. So, if the software you are using is not offering obvious solutions, hopefully they have an API you can use to query them about their state, and then trigger alerts.